# SQL Server query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to achieve something like the following sql statements in a transaction. Can anyone advice how I can accomplish this? most importantly, there shouldnt be any dirty read or write. Thanks!

```
UPDATE items SET assigned = 1 
WHERE 
    SELECT TOP 1 @item_no = item_no
    FROM items
    WHERE item_code = @item_code 
    AND store_id = @store_id

UPDATE parts SET issued = 1 
WHERE 
    SELECT TOP 1 @part_no = part_no 
    FROM parts
    WHERE part_id = part_id 

INSERT INTO issued_hardware (@item_no, @part_no, DateTime.now, @username);
```

Comment: I assume you mean there _shouldn't_ be any dirty reads or writes? If so, fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have mentioned you use a transaction and its isolation state to control Dirty Reads. I recommend against this since it means you can read an uncommitted transaction that may fail which can cause race conditions that are difficult to trace down.

Also since you're doing more that one data modification you should probably explicitly roll back your transaction. Finally your SQL needed to fixed. Taking advantage of the output clause is probably a good idea.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY


     DECLARE @Item table (item_no int )
     DECLARE @part table (part_no int)

     UPDATE TOP 1 ITEMS 
     SET assigned = 1
     WHERE   
            item_code = @item_code 
            AND store_id = @store_id
     OUTPUT
            inserted.item_no 
     INTO @Item 

     UPDATE TOP 1 parts 
     SET issued = 1
     OUTPUT
            inserted.part_no
     INTO @part


     INSERT INTO issued_hardware 
     SELECT item_no, GetDate(), @UserName
     FROM @item, @part;





END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Comment: hi, just wondering if other transaction can overwrite the item parameter and part parameter values which will cause an inaccurate insert.

Comment: variables local to batch or stored procedure are local to the execution so no it can't be overridden.

Comment: i using command.CommandText = "sql statement here"

do you recommend that i should change it to a stored procedure and call it from my method?

Comment: it works either way so its up to you. You should consider using [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx) if you go with the command text and the parameters (store_id, item_code ) are from user input.

Comment: thanks, Conrad. One last question though. How do you declare "DECLARE @Item table (item_no int )" using a parameterized  query? or can i dump them in my sql statement? string sql = "DECLARE @'Item table (item_no int )DECLARE @'part table (part_no int)UPDATE TOP 1 ITEMS....." ?

Comment: I was mistaken if you want to use commandtext you'll need to either use transaction object or transaction scope. You'll also need to output the values rather than do into @item and then pass them back in. If it were me I'd go with a Stored Proc on this one

Answer (score 2):

You just have to enable your appropriate isolation level and encapsulate your query in `BEGIN TRAN identifier`, `COMMIT TRAN identifier`.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
BEGIN TRAN T1;
UPDATE items SET assigned = 1 
WHERE 
    SELECT TOP 1 @item_no = item_no
    FROM items
    WHERE item_code = @item_code 
    AND store_id = @store_id;

UPDATE parts SET issued = 1 
WHERE 
    SELECT TOP 1 @part_no = part_no 
    FROM parts
    WHERE part_id = part_id;

INSERT INTO issued_hardware (@item_no, @part_no, DateTime.now, @username);
COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear, but i'll try to answer.

You just try to frame the query between

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRAN

your query here

COMMIT
```

and do not forget to frame your subqueries with round braces, or something else - because your queries are not syntaxically correct

And especially - if you want the dirty reads from other transactioned data inside your transaciton - use tables with (nolock) postfix

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more detail. What programming language are you using? What component to connect to the database? Are you writing the application in MS Visual Studio?

Or are you just trying to execute all this in a script, in a single transaction?

At first sight, I would recommend putting all the code above into a stored MSSQL procedure, and call the procedure from the application's code. That way you can commit or revert the whole transaction and also keep the logic in one place, in the database. Also, it's easier to modify the procedure in SQL and mantain afterwards than in your app that would need recompiling.

Comment: im using visual studio and ms sql 2008. im executing the queries in a method

Comment: Ok, please see [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/transactions.aspx) that describes using ADO transactions. The key is to use db.BeginTransaction(), transaction.Commit() and transaction.Rollback()

Comment: As for using stored procedures in ADO, see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simplecodeasp.aspx). Also, if this is the case and the question is related to db transactions in .Net, you should consider editing your question and add the tags C# and .Net